# How to programmatically set volume in Windows, Mac and Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, macos

I'd like to programmatically set volume in Windows, Mac and Ubuntu using C/C++. Command line also can but C/C++ preferred. Thank you in advance!

Comment: by volume do yo mean the audio volume?

Comment: Yes. I want to set the master volume.

Comment: You're going to get three *very* different answers. I recommend you ask three *separate* questions for this. That way, you're more likely to get responses that answer the *entire* question instead of what you're getting here, which only answer 1/3 of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually only MacOS is left. I didn't figure out that I need to nominate the best answer for each question.

Answer (score 4):

Just a hint, In windows the 'philosophy' around volume adjustment has changed between XP and Vista/7. Code that would change the master volume on XP will only change the application specific volume setting in the mixer on Vista and 7.

Here is a good blog post by one of the MS audio dev team regarding this: [Larry Osterman's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/12/15/504158.aspx)

Here are some codeproject pages that might prove useful:

[For XP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/mixerSetControlDetails.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=16481&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2765918)

[For Vista +](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx?msg=2792476)

Also, there are a few powerpoint presentations regarding the new api's here:
[AMP Summit ppts](http://ampalliance.org/blogs/microsoft/archive/2007/08/14/Microsoft-AMP-Summit-Decks.aspx). The Audio Endpoints in Windows Vista presentation has some good info.

As for OsX and Ubuntu, i have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

For Linux using ALSA sound system, you can use following command:

```
amixer set Master 50%
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! Does it have the same effect as adjusting the speaker icon on the Taskbar? This one does not look like C system call but thanks anyway.

Comment: It is a shell command, you can execute it with system() or fork()/exec(). And yes, it has the same effect as adjusting taskbar volume control.

Comment: I wish I knew C/C++ functions to do the same thing. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Then you should look into ALSA library (http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___mixer.html), which isn't very well documented, or peek into amixer sources;)

Comment: This DOES NOT WORK in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake, here is the OSX cli version:

```
osascript -e "set volume output volume (output volume of (get volume settings)+2)"
```

And on the C side it's more difficult. From everything I found researching this, the easiest way is using one of the readily available objective C answers and wrapping them into a function in an extra object you can call from C/C++.