# C# get master volume level/precent

Tags: c#, .net

I got this code to mute/unmute the master volume

```
private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
```

I would to know how can I get the master volume level/precent because I want to know if the sound is already muted or not.

Edit:
or else I would like to split the mute/unmute sound so I will have two functions - one for mute and one for unmute.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not do it for all Windows versions (xp, vista & 7).
Though, I achieved it by used external programs, such as [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), and sent the command I needed.

not so good solution but it did solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx

They created an own mixer control, that also reports the current volumne and the mute/unmute state:

```
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.OnVolumeNotification += new AudioEndpointVolumeNotificationDelegate(
    AudioEndpointVolume_OnVolumeNotification);
// .. snip ..
void AudioEndpointVolume_OnVolumeNotification(AudioVolumeNotificationData data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("New Volume {0}", data.MasterVolume);
    Console.WriteLine("Muted      {0}", data.Muted);
}
```

Does this help you?

EDIT: With this code and the class from the project you should be able to set and unset mute directly (without toggle):

```
MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
MMDevice defaultDevice = devEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = true; // or false
```

Comment: CodeProject link is dead

Comment: This works wonders. Note that you'll need to reference NAudio.dll with the following namespace: using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;. MasterVolumeLevelScalar is a linear 0-1 scale, whereas MasterVolumeLevel is some non-linear scale.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/05dc2d35-1d45-4837-8e16-562ee919da85) shows how to control the master volume from C#.

You might also be interested in the responses to this question: [Get Master Sound Volume in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534595/get-master-sound-volume-in-c)

Especially the [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) managed wrapper.

Comment: What, specifically, didn't work? Comments in the thread indicate that it works.

Comment: used the function GetVolume() and it returned 65535, after i changed the volume it returned me the same value - 65535. maybe I'm using the wrong function?

Comment: That other question is about the intensity of the currently playing sound, not the gain currently set in the mixer.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer. none of the threads that Jim gave are working.