# How do I get the loudness of the current sound coming from the master audio channel?

Tags: .net, vb.net, audio, windows-7

I would like to create a visualizer for the windows system audio. I'm looking for a way to sample the loudness of the sound currently being played. I don't need the actual sound unless required for computing the sound levels. My goal is to create something similar to the bouncing green level found on windows 7's volume control. My Googling up to this point suggests that this is may be impossible. Thanks for any advice!

[image]

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235246/c-sharp-get-master-volume-level-precent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [CoreAudioApi](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx) in a similar project. I believe it will suit your needs.