# Control the computer's volume in C#

Tags: c#, controls, media, volume, trackbar

Is there a way to control the computer's actual volume in C# and display that in a vertical track bar??

I have tried practically everything, but there must be something I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: _"Practically everything"_ is not very helpful for ruling out answers we *don't* have to suggest anymore because you've already tried them.

Comment: @stakx practically everything means that I went through the .Net framework, but nothing did the trick

Comment: Related question: [C# get master volume level/percent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235246/c-sharp-get-master-volume-level-precent).

Comment: Found a good Youtube video about how to do this. Here it is:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZY29YUqz3lE

I have watched it and it works well.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I have to wait for 8 hours before I can do that.

Comment: @HBellamy: Alright then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `winmm.dll` library through p/Invoke?

That's what this article recommends: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c%23/

He's (strangely) licensed his code with GPL, so I can't post it here.  But it is pretty basic and simply calls various mixer methods.

There's another winmm wrapper with an MIT license you can get here: http://winmm.codeplex.com/.  It will have the same underlying code, but you won't have to GPL your code when you use it.