# Control speaker volumes with c#

Tags: c#, audio, windows-7

is there any easy way to control the individual speaker volumes in Windows 7 with c#?

I just want to set the volumes to a "preset", because windows likes to reset them randomly...

Answer (score 0):

Start here,

Use [IAudioMeterInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368227%28VS.85%29.aspx) in the CoreAudio APIs in Vista and Win 7.

Managed wrappers are available in [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) (get at the AudioMeterInformation from the MMDevice).

check this too [Get Master Sound Volume in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534595/get-master-sound-volume-in-c-sharp)