# Show waveform of playing sound

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

Let's say I want to make a simple application that can play sounds. In WPF, I can use either the [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) class or the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx) class to take care of the playback.

Is it possible to actually extract data from the playing sound in order to draw the playing sound as a waveform (possibly using a charting library)? Something like in the image below. Alternatively, is it possible to at least obtain and display the output volume as we see in the Windows speakers system tray icon (second image below)?

[image: Waveform]

[image]

Comment: This might be of use http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3352/A-low-level-audio-player-in-C

Comment: For the 2nd part , you can use this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534595/get-master-sound-volume-in-c-sharp