# NAaudio output device problems

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, speaker

I am making my game engine in c# (OpenTK and Naudio). I bought another monitor and now i have 3 audio outputs. My heaphones are set as the main ones but naudio just sends audio to my monitor, even when I do this:

```
Wave.DeviceNumber = -1;
```

The audio just  comes out of my monitor I am just playing an waveout with volume control and, when mono, panning control.

PS: I am compiling for windows 10. And this is my github issue : https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/283

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077907/get-default-output-audio-device-with-naudio is what you are looking for

Comment: I guess you can use ```MMDeviceEnumerator.GetDevice()``` to get the identifier of the default media playback device and use that in wave but honestly I don't know

Comment: but dont i need an int to do this: wave.DeviceNumber = int

Comment: Yes and the MMDeviceEnumerator will give you an int.
Have you checked the content of WaveOut.DeviceCount to know if it even recognizes the other outputs you have besides the monitor?

Comment: i am just a noob in audio. I worked with windows audio core api. How do I play a wave in a certain device

Comment: Sorry, I'm not your man. I'm a rookie in audio stuff, too. I hope someone else will help you.

Comment: i tried and even windows audio player (bundled with .NET) just works on the speakers