# How to control master volume in C++/visualc++ for windows7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7

Am trying to control the master volume in C++/VisualC++ for windows7/vista? Any suggesions Please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920749/how-to-programmatically-set-volume-in-windows-mac-and-ubuntu

Comment: Hi I have seen that link.. but the suggesions in that link are in c#. But i need in c++/visualc++. @David Saxon

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you wanna control the sounds in your computer here is a helpful 
link.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb331828(VS.85).aspx

Hope this helps.