# Decrease OSX say command volume in Python code

Tags: python, macos

Right now I am using the command:

```
system("say Hello World!")
```

to have the system say "Hello World!".

How do I decrease the volume?

Comment: it's not a python question. Check `say` manual.

Comment: These questions may help you: [Adjust OSX System Audio Volume in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565204/adjust-osx-system-audio-volume-in-python) and [How to programmatically set volume in Windows, Mac and Ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920749/how-to-programmatically-set-volume-in-windows-mac-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `osascript` utility to set the system volume before invoking `say`:

```
system("osascript -e 'set Volume 1'")
system("say Hello World!")
```

Comment: Indeed, this will do as asked and set the systems volume (and thus also lowering the volume of the systems voice). Fun note: you could also go to `System Preferences > Accessibility > select Voice on the left side > System Voice menu > select Customize > select Whisper > press OK` now your Mac will download this voice and you could do `system("say -v Whisper Hello World!"`)

Comment: I just came here to say I followed the advice to enable the "whisper" voice and it's incredibly creepy. I'm still keeping it, but man is it creepy.